# Do serializable transaction isolation level guarantee that non-DB code is also serialised?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, transactions, isolation-level

I need to run some DB operations AND produce event to Kafka topic. However, the event content depends on what is read from DB and order of events matters. Consider such operations:

1. open transaction
2. read from table
3. update table
4. read from table again
5. emit event to topic
6. commit transaction

Now I know that serializable isolation level guarantees that data in database are consistent. Two service instances running this operations at the same time are always going to read valid data, as if transactions were run sequentially. But is it true also for emitting event to Kafka topic?

Is such scenario possible:

1. Instance A runs, reads data and prepares event to emit
2. Instance B runs, reads data AS IF IT WAS RUN AFTER A and prepares event to emit
3. Instance B emits the event
4. Instance A emits the event

In above scenario order of events is wrong. If instance A prepared the event based on data before the changes introduced by instance B, its' event should be emitted first.

I think this question boils down to the question when transaction B is going to fail? Does it fail on point 4 - because the data was changed by another transaction? Or does it fail on commit - after Kafka event was already produced?

Or is it possible that there is no failure at all? Like in this scenario:

1. A reads
2. A updates
3. A reads again
4. B reads (data already updated by A)
5. B updates
6. B reads again      -- no conflict, because B runs all DB operations after A
7. B emits event
8. A emits event

No error thrown but events order is wrong

The best solution should be DB-angnostic but if it matters I use PostgreSQL 10.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #2 "Instance B emits the event..." will fail when using `SERIALIZABLE`.

Let's try it out. Let's create a table:

```
create table t (id int, amount int);

insert into t (id, amount) values (1, 500), (2, 1000);
```

Now, let's run instance #1:

```
start transaction isolation level serializable not deferrable;

select amount from t where id = 1; -- shows $500

update t set amount = amount - 100 where id = 1;

select amount from t where id = 1; -- shows $400

-- wait here while instance #2 works...
```

Now, let's run instance #2:

```
    start transaction isolation level serializable not deferrable;

    select amount from t where id = 1; -- shows $500!

    update t set amount = amount - 150 where id = 1;
    -- the thread blocks...
```

Now, back to instance #1:

```
commit; -- all good
```

And, then back to instance #2, that stopped waiting:

```
    Error: ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update
    SQLState:  40001
    ErrorCode: 0
```

As you see, when you use `SERIALIZABLE` the threads try to run in parallel as long as they don't step into each other toes. The minute they do "one wins" and continue processing, while the other one waits; hopefully the other one won't make too much *damage* to the state of the data. In this case instance #1 did actually do some damage to instance #2 (it changed the data), so the latter failed.

Comment: Are you sure that applies to logical decoding as welk?

Comment: Thank you @The_Impaler! In this fragment: `update t set amount = amount - 150 where id = 1;
    -- the thread blocks...` - what if the thread does not block? From your answer I assume instance #2 fails only when #1 did commit? What if it didn't, and both transactions get to commit (send event)? And only then one of them does commit?

Comment: The other transaction rolls back and throws error, but the event might be already emitted?

Comment: @amorfis If you were using JMS (e.g. ActiveMQ) the emission of the message and the database transaction would be a single atomic unit, and your entire question here would be a non-issue. However, you are using Kafka, that doesn't support transactions. The new "transaction-free" solution -- that requires a lot of coding/support effort, btw -- is to use a "Transactional Outbox" with idempotent mesages; for example, see https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html

Comment: @TheImpaler I found better solution using database locks :) Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @amorfis If you found a better solution, can you add it as an answer? Just a brief description will do.

Answer (score -1):

I guess that since you mention Kafka, you mean logical decoding produces data when you say that an instance "emits" something.

I don't think that the `SERIALIZABLE` Isolation level gives any guarantees about the order in which WAL will be loed ir decoded. It only concerns the effects on the data as seen with SQL.

Comment: But that's enough. If SQL is good, order of events is good too. It is all described in the question. If transactions don't "step on each other's toes" - order doesn't matter. If it does, event is not going to be emitted because transaction is going to throw error before the emission.

Comment: If you are convinced, that is good. I am not convinced.

Comment: Important is when the error is thrown. If it's before producing event to Kafka - it is not going to be produced. If it's only on commit - event is already produced and order is broken.